# Error al ocupar map en react js

Tags: reactjs

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy trayendo unas rutas de imágenes que están almacenadas en firebase. Tengo una función que traen datos y los ordena para después mostrarlo en la galería de imágenes.
El tema es que no logro hacer el ciclo con map y me tira el siguiente error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y es así como viene el array con los objetos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la función que muestra la galería :

```
function CarouselResponsive(props) {

  var src = props.imgSrc 

  console.log('src' , src);


  var galery = src.map( row =>
    <div key={row.url}>
      <img src={row.url} alt=""/>
      <p className="legend">{row.legend}</p>
    </div>
  )

  return <Carousel>
    {galery }
  </Carousel>
}
```

y de aquí es donde lo llamo el componente

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <CarouselResponsive imgSrc={ getDataCarousel() }/>
    </div>
  )
}

function getDataCarousel(){  

  var dataFiles = [];
  db.collection('files_home_carousel').get().then(( querySnapshot ) => {

    querySnapshot.forEach( (doc , index) => {
      var file = doc.data()
      dataFiles.push({
        url : file.file ,
        legend : file.legend
      })
    })
  })

  return dataFiles
}
```

Cualquier comentario es bienvenido, saludos

Comment: Te da primero el error y luego te pinta los datos por consola?. Aún así me miraría los ciclos de vida de los componentes y esa llamada a firebase la haría en el componentDidMount si estas usando componentes de clase o usaría useEffect en el caso que sea componentes funcionales.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @IDanny7 tienes que hacer el request de tus imagenes usando `useEffect(() => getDataCarousel() , [])`

Comment: uno de los problemas es que la función getDataCarousel esta retornando el valor vacío ya que dataFiles.push se esta haciendo dentro de una promesa entonces siempre lo primero que va a hacer es ejecutar return dataFiles